# Responsibility of image size in model/view concept

Tags: qt, qt5, model-view

I'm preparing view which will display images. Model for this view is feeded with high resolution photos which are stored as thumbnails and passed to view as `Qt::DecorationRole`.

The problem I have is that I plan to allow user to change thumbnail size and I'm a little bit confused how to do this right.

I think original data (thumbnail sizes) in model should not change as in theory there can be many views attached.

My idea is to store original images in model, scaled a little bit to avoid too high memory consumption and then view(s) will resize them down to the appropriate size. But is it how it should be done?

Comment: Your idea is sound. It'll be the view's role to change the size of the displayed elements. You can cache the scaled versions, too.

Comment: Thx for comments. I was a little bit affraid how would regular views like `QTreeView` work with big image provided as `DecorationRole`, but right usage of `QIcon` with proper size in `Qt::SizeHintRole` works nicely.